# How to change network interface connection timeout in systemctl

Tags: debian, systemd, startup, timeout, lsb

When I boot my Debian system, its startup hangs for approximately 2 minutes on the line:

```
Loading, please wait...
[    5.191043] systemd-fsck[129]: /dev/mmcblk0p2: clean, 234192/873120 files, 2335263/3491328 blocks
[    6.645242] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
[    6.643682] systemd-fsck[222]: fsck.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
[    6.664844] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
[    6.660702] systemd-fsck[222]: /dev/mmcblk0p1: 3 files, 33/130812 clusters
[    **] A start job is running for LSB: Raise network interf...38s / no limit)
```

Eventually, it gives up on raising the network interface and continues booting.

**Question:** How can I change the timeout used in `systemctl`, so that after 15 seconds it stops trying to raise the network interface?

**Additional info:** the source of the problem is the use of a wifi USB dongle on this machine. Sometimes the dongle is there, sometimes it's not. When the dongle is not plugged in, I expect the network interface to not be raised, and I just don't want to wait for too long.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a similar problem and was scratching my head over the lack of Google results (after ending up at this page a few times), so I decided to just read up on how `systemd` works [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files).

Eventually I figured out that `networking` is actually a SysV init script (`/etc/init.d/networking`), which is converted to a `systemd` service at runtime (`/run/systemd/generator.late/networking.service`), so you can't just modify an existing script.

Instead you have to override it with a file at e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/reduce-timeout.conf`, in your case containing:

```
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=15
```

Answer (score 7):

On a system running Debian Jessie, I was able to append the following code to the file located at `/lib/systemd/system/networking.service.d/network-pre.conf`

```
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=15
```

This changed 'no limit' to a limit of 15 seconds, making the system boot much faster if network is disconnected.

Creating a file in `/etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/` did not have any effect on this system, so I edited the existing file in the `/lib/systemd/system/networking.service.d/`. If this directory is empty, creating a new .conf file with the code above should work.

Not sure why this is different or if it's even the correct way to configure such a thing.

Comment: this solution worked for me too. The accepted one did not.

Comment: AFAIK `/lib/systemd/...` is intended for original scripts, and `/etc/systemd/...` for local overriding, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you. I'm also on Jessie.

Comment: `/lib/systemd/system/networking.service` contained in stretch a timeout of 5min!!

Comment: @Proctoru2 Maybe you needed to run `systemctl daemon-reload`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364782/what-does-systemctl-daemon-reload-do#:~:text=After%20installing%20new%20generators%20or,(1)%20for%20more%20information.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, and it turns out my system was trying to connect to Wi-Fi. My solution involved changing this line in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto wlan0
```

to:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
```

Comment: this worked well for my Asus P5Q board which has four NICs (it's hard to know which one of the four is assigned as eth0). I changed `auto eth0` to `allow-hotplug eth0` \n `allow-hotplug eth1` \n `allow-hotplug eth2` \n `allow-hotplug eth3`

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in the Debian's networking scripts -- they apparently wait for all interfaces to appear and do not have a notion of "dynamically appearing" interfaces (like `systemd-networkd` does).

You have two solutions. The first solution is to reduce the configuration timeout. However, as can be seen from the output you have posted (`...38s / no limit`), systemd does not impose any timeouts on the network startup. So this is something you need to configure in the Debian-specific scripts themselves.

The second solution is to use more modern tools to configure your network (like NetworkManager) which support dynamically appearing interfaces. Note that `systemd-networkd` won't be of much use here because it has no integrated support for WLAN networks.

Comment: Thank you intelfx for your response. Any lead as to how to configure the timeout in `systemd` in the Debian-specific scripts? Any pointer toward some kind of solution would be much appreciated! (I spent lots of time googling and empirically messing with options with no success so far)

Comment: @Jealie: I have never used Debian or any of its derivatives, so I can't help you here, sorry. It would be better if you added a "debian" tag to your question, but you have rejected my edit which suggested exactly that change...

Comment: @Jealle: Ah, hm, I must've misread something then... sorry.