# Debian A start job is running for Unattended Upgrades

Tags: debian

I use  Unattended Upgrades on my system, everything is working fine.
I just notice something I don't understand, when I reboot some server I got stuck with the following message :

```
"A start job is running for Unattended Upgrades (5min 34s / not limit"
```

After some reboot this message disappear.
Any idea on what is going wrong ? 
I checked the log but I don't find anything.

I am running Debian 8 up to date.

Comment: There is no daemon for unattended upgrades as far as I know. I want to reboot the server my self, so I disabled auto reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

when the system shuts down all services will be shut down with:
/etc/init.d/name_of_service stop

but unattended-upgrades doesn't start at boot because reasons, and this confuses it at shutdown so to fix this
open crontab as root (sudo crontab -e) and put in:

"@reboot /etc/init.d/unattended-upgrades start"

This fixed it for me so i hope it will for all others as well

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible aswer in [other thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186162/how-to-change-timeout-in-systemctl#264286).

I had a similar problem when shutting down. It showed "A start job is running for Unattended Upgrades (time / 15min 02s)"

I'm using Debian Stretch and found a file at

```
/lib/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.service
```

This file has a line with:

```
TimeoutStartSec=900
```

I've changed that from 900 to 15 and the message now has a limit of 16 seconds. I don't know why it adds some time beyond this configuration.

Answer (score -1):

type this in root terminal mode :

update-rc.d -f unattended-upgrades remove

systemctl stop unattended-upgrades

This for 1 session. Cardinal decision :

Remove package:  Unattended Upgrades

Comment: The OP wants to use Unattended Upgrades, and your proposal to fix the issue they've encountered is to remove the Unattended Upgrades facility? I don't think so.