# Running script at shutdown and reboot to prevent chromium session loss

Tags: systemd, shutdown, reboot, runlevel, systemctl

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 and I'm trying to create a script that shuts down Chromium properly before shutting down the system so that it doesn't give me "restore session" popup after booting. I figured I'll use killall to this and came up with
`/home/shutdownscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash 
killall -HUP "chromium-browser --enable-pinch"
```

that seems to do the trick.

However, now I have a problem with actually running this script at shutdown or reboot.

First thing I tried was  putting it in `/etc/init.d` as `shutdownscript` with `chmod +x` and then symlinking it to `rc0.d` and `rc6.d` as `K99shutdownscript` and later `K01ashutdownscript`. However, that didn't work for me.

I thought maybe I should just create a new systemd service, so I created `shutdownscript.service` in `/etc/systemd/system` with contents like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Saves Chromium session

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/istir/shutdownscript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I ran `systemctl start shutdownscript.service` and `systemctl enable shutdownscript.service` but it still didn't work as intended.

The solution is probably very simple but I returned to Linux after around 6 years of using Windows and macOS so I don't really remember what did I do earlier to make shutdown scripts.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would swear it happens by default with Firefox and Chrome in Linux.

Comment: I guess it should but for me it doesn't even on fresh installation with only Chromium installed. When I close chromium normally and then reboot everything is as it should, but if I leave chromium open and reboot then it tells me to restore session. It's not critical, just kinda pain to do every time.

Comment: Instead of working around it, I suggest you look into the original issue of Chromium not shutting down properly on reboot. (It should!) Maybe start with [this question](https://superuser.com/q/697618/879179) which might have some ideas of what to try already. Otherwise, try to give more details about which desktop environment and/or window manager are you using, where you installed Chromium from, how you're rebooting the machine, etc. to troubleshoot that. I suggest asking a new question (as this one is about other stuff.) Maybe consider asking at AskUbuntu, might get more answers there.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364787/270935), we might need to run the following after configuring systemctl.

```
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And we should have a header in the script like [below](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts).

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    
# Required-Stop:     
# Default-Start:     0 1 6
# Default-Stop:      
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: Still no luck, when using `systemctl enable` it actually gives an error 
`update-rc.d: error: shutdownscript Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.`

Comment: @istir try the header as updated in the answer.

Comment: I succeeded in enabling the script and running it but it still doesn't  do what I want it to do. Maybe I should change Default-start to 0 6? IIRC these are numbers for shutdown and reboot.
I had to change `shutdownscript.service` to `shutdownscriptnew.service` because I couldn't enable it otherwise.

However, when running `sudo systemctl stop shutdownscriptnew.service` it actually does what it should and closes chromium.

Comment: yes we should start at run level 0,1 and 6

Comment: Still no luck, I tried changing Default-Start and Default-Stop and even ExecStart and ExecStop - if I run `systemctl stop shutdownscriptnew.service` it closes chromium, but if I reboot it doesn't do anything and it still terminates it so that I have to restore session.